# Flutter Default Image Placeholder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

In my data i have posts, but some having image urls and others have `false` value, while displaying i want to show the placeholder where value are `false`

**Here is my code :**

```
     child: FadeInImage(
  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
  image: NetworkImage(posts[index].featuredImage.large ) == null ? 
   Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png') : NetworkImage(posts[index].featuredImage.large ),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the condition `posts[index].featuredImage.large` in a `NetworkImage` widget.

Just check if the string coming from the API is null, then set the default `Image` as `Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png')` and if it is not null set the `Image` as `NetworkImage(posts[index].featuredImage.large )`.

Try the code below:

```
FadeInImage(
          placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
          image: posts[index].featuredImage.large  == null ?
          Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png') : NetworkImage(posts[index].featuredImage.large ),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This how you can do it

```
child: post[index].url==false? Image.assets('assets/images/placeholder.png'): FadeInImage(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
  image: posts[index].featuredImage.large == null ? 
   Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png') : NetworkImage(posts[index].featuredImage.large ),
),
```

But there will be an issue here if your url is declared as `String` since `false` is not a `String` and comparing different data type is not a good idea . Then you will have to check `RuntimeType`

E.g: `post[index].url is String`//true if url is a String

Comment: featured_image":{"thumbnail":false,"medium":false,"large":false}}]

Comment: It looks like you didn't clearly explained your needs. as i see you want to look for each of those images if it is a link or not. if there is no link, then you will display a placeholder issn't i?